# Getting "ValueError: invalid vertex descriptor" when removing vertices

Tags: python, graph-tool

I have no idea what causes this error. What I do is adding *a lot* of vertices to my graph at the beginning:

```
for i in range(len(repositories_key_list)):
    repo_vertices[repositories_key_list[i]] = g3.add_vertex()
```

Then comes some processing that connects those vertices and in order to reduce the time it takes to render the graph I remove all verticies that have in and out degree equal to zero:

```
for repository_name in repo_vertices:

    vert = repo_vertices[repository_name]
    print vert

    if vert.out_degree() == 0 and vert.in_degree() == 0:
        g3.remove_vertex(vert)
```

However, something I do seems to be a problem because I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sfalk/win-data/Stefan/Uni/Master/WS/Network Science/projects/project1/github/graph_tools_github.py", line 276, in <module>
    print vert
ValueError: invalid vertex descriptor: 22947
```

Interestingly the  `print vert` gets traced back as an issue here. If I comment that line out I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/sfalk/win-data/Stefan/Uni/Master/WS/Network Science/projects/project1/github/graph_tools_github.py", line 278, in <module>
    if vert.out_degree() == 0 and vert.in_degree() == 0:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graph_tool/__init__.py", line 2933, in _out_degree
    return self.__out_degree()
ValueError: invalid vertex descriptor: 23038
```

So whatever happens here, I have no idea how to solve it ..

Answer (score 0):

This is described in detail in the documentation for `Graph.remove_vertex()` at https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.Graph.remove_vertex. Namely, it states:

> This operation may invalidate vertex descriptors. Vertices are always
>   indexed contiguously in the range [0,N−1], hence vertex descriptors
>   with an index higher than `vertex` will be invalidated after removal (if
>   fast == False, otherwise only descriptors pointing to vertices with
>   the largest index will be invalidated).
>
> Because of this, the only safe way to remove more than one vertex at
>   once is to sort them in decreasing index order:

```
# 'del_list' is a list of vertex descriptors
for v in reversed(sorted(del_list)):
    g.remove_vertex(v)
```

> Alternatively (and preferably), a list (or iterable) may be passed
>   directly as the `vertex` parameter, and the above is performed
>   internally (in C++).

Comment: I'm still unclear on this: is there a way to remove an arbitrary vertex without invalidating at least one other vertex?